# HTML Image graph that is interactable/clickable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to display a graph similar to the one below. I would like it if the nodes (A, B, C, ...) could be clickable and from that I could display a little pop up menu giving the user options of what they wish to do.

I'm aware that I could display something like this with canvas but from my understanding I would then have to figure out the coordinates for each node (there might be 50+) to write the click functions.

I'm just looking for direction for a way to do this, either with standard html, css, js or using a library (if using a library I'll need the graph to be pannable and interactable on mobile).

[image: Example of a graph I might want to display]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I've heard d3js is a good way to deal with canvas interactions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a canvas. You surely know where you put the letters. Whenever you put a letter, just store its coordinates and implement a function which would tell you whether a given X, Y pair is inside the rectangle of a given letter. Assuming that you stored an array letters, where you have startX, startY, endX, endY members, then you can do something like this:

```
function isInRectangle(letter, x, y) {
    return ((x >= letter.startX) && (y >= letter.startY) && (x <= letter.endX) && (y <= letter.endY));
}

function getClickedLetter(letters, x, y) {
    for (var letter of letters) if (isInRectangle(letter, x, y)) return letter;
    //by default returns undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use html `<svg>` tag (instead canvas) to do this easily https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/. You can also use Vue/Angular get even better results (simpler code).